# How do I keep the title of the webpage visible when the navigation bar is hidden, like in iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to reproduce the behaviour of iOS Safari's navigation bar, wherein a title holder is shown after the navigation bar is hidden:

## iOS Safari behaviour

When the navigation bar is fully visible, it shows the webpage's title text.

When the navigation bar is hidden, the title text is still visible at the top of the screen. I am not sure whether this is part of the functionality of normal navigation bars, or whether it is made bespoke.

[image: Safari appearance]

---

## My ViewController's behaviour

### Relevant code

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
    view = webView!
    searchBar = UISearchBar()
    searchBar!.delegate = self // just using searchBarSearchButtonClicked()
    searchBar!.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.minimal
    searchBar!.showsCancelButton = true
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
}
```

### Behaviour

I am happy with the navigation bar's current appearance in this state (I am fine with it showing the URL rather than the webpage title).

However, when my navigation bar hides, it really does hide completely, leaving no title behind. How can I keep a title holder visible here?

[image: Mine]

Comment: Why are you not using the SFSafariViewController? https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller

Comment: Because my full project involves a lot of Javascript injection, which SFSafariViewController does not allow.

Comment: Ok. But I would not use the UISearchBar like that. It makes the animation difficult. However you could change the styling of it and animate from one state to the other while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library: https://github.com/bryankeller/BLKFlexibleHeightBar. However note that it is NOT a UINavigationBar subclass. So in case you will need some NavigationBar built-in functionality (like "Back" button, etc.) you will need to implement it yourself.

Comment: I'd like to avoid using a framework and instead learn exactly how I can approach the task myself – also since it's in Objective C it looks like it will take a lot of effort and hours to pick apart the important aspects of it (this was a Swift question). That said, the "TrendyStartup.io" example gif does look promising. I will look into this if absolutely nothing else works out, but in any case would be more likely to accept an answer (likely mine at this rate) reporting back on the key approach of the framework and how it could be reproduced in Swift.

Comment: Tried to implement it myself using AutoLayout on a UIView containing two subViews which are shown/hidden upon swipe, and got close, but can't get my changing height constraints to animate, even with `layoutIfNeeded()`. Investigated your suggested library and found a [branch that converts it to Swift](https://github.com/rabzu/BLKFlexibleHeightBar/tree/swift). However, the library ultimately doesn't appear to support changing phone orientation, so it doesn't get me any further than I'd started.